# Making tabs interactive in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r

Is is possible to make the tabs interactive for the below code. So, only when I select "B" from the dropdown, Tab B should be open

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Loading data"),
dashboardSidebar(fileInput("datafile","Choose the csv file",multiple = TRUE, 
                           accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
                   ("Or"),
                 fileInput("datafile1","Choose the excel file",multiple = TRUE, 
                           accept = c(".xlsx")),
                 selectInput("S","Select Tabs",choices = c("A","B"))),
dashboardBody(
  tabBox(fluidRow(title = "Dataset",uiOutput("filter_70"),width = 5000),fluidRow(title="B"))
))

server <- function(input,output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi all, can anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using tab controls in Shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel")

  ), 
  tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
         tabPanel("Visualisation", 
                  width = 12, 
                  height = 800
         )


  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
            food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

            tabPanel(food[i], 
                     checkboxGroupInput(paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                        label = NULL, 
                                        choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                          filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                          select(Product_name) %>%
                                          unlist(use.names = FALSE)),
                     checkboxInput(paste0("all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)
          )
          })))

      ) # end of Tab box



      # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see",choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))
      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices = product_choices,
                                   selected = product_choices)
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices =product_choices)
        }
      }
    })
  })

} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Now, if you want to use Shiny to import datasets and have some tab controls to select different views, you can do it this way.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My shiny app"), sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("This app shows how a user can upload a csv file. Then, plot the data.
          Any file can be uploaded but analysis is only available
          if the data is in same format as the sample file, downloadable below
          "),
  a("Data to be plotted", href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3q2eayogbe0bgl/shiny_data.csv?dl=0"),
  tags$hr(),
  fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
  br(),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
),
mainPanel(
  uiOutput("tb"),
  plotOutput("line")             
)
)
)

#server.R
server <- function(input,output){
data <- reactive({


file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()} 

read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)})

output$filedf <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
input$file
}) 

output$sum <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
summary(data())
})

output$table <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
data()
})

output$line <- renderPlot({
if (is.null(data())) { return() }
print(ggplot(data(), aes(x=date, y=aa)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~station)) })

output$tb <- renderUI({if(is.null(data()))
h5()               
else
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]